# Querying Cart Line Attributes - Shopify GraphQL

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm pretty new to Shopify app development, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious here.

I'm building a Shopify app that will sometimes add additional CartLine properties when adding to the cart. I have this part working; when I call the `cart/add` api, I can see the properties being passed if they were selected.

Now I am trying to add a Shopify discount function, that will use these properties (e.g., field_a). I'm using [this tutorial](https://shopify.dev/apps/discounts/create#step-4-add-and-deploy-a-product-discount-extension) as a reference.

GraphQL Input:

```
query Input {
  cart {
    lines {
      attribute {
        field_a
      }
      merchandise {
        ...on ProductVariant {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Api.rs:

```
    #[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
    pub struct CartLine {
        pub quantity: Int,
        pub merchandise: Merchandise,
        pub attribute: AttributeList,
    }

    #[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize)]
    pub struct AttributeList {
        #[serde(default="_default_false")]
        pub field_a: i64,
    }
    fn _default_false() -> i64 { 0 }
```

However, when I try and deploy my Shopify App, I get the error below. This seems to be because field_a is not always available in the data being queried?

```
│  The deployment of functions failed with the following errors:                                         
│  [                                                                                                     
│    {                                                                                                   
│      "field": null,                                                                                    
│      "message": "Field 'field_a' doesn't exist on type 'Attribute' at 'query                             
│  Input.cart.lines.property.field_a'",                                                                   │
│      "tag": "input_query_validation_error"                                                             
│    }                                                                                                   
│  ]
```

Does anyone have suggestions for me to fix this error? I've tried defining field_a as an Option and I've tried setting a default for the entire AttributeList struct, but I keep getting the same error when I run `npm run deploy`....

Comment: did you ever work this out I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
query Input {
  cart {
    lines {
      field_a: attribute (key: "field_a") {
        value
      }
      merchandise {
        ...on ProductVariant {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

field_a is an alias. doesn't have to match the key